# How do I collect and throw Validation Errors manually?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django Rest Framework 2.4.
I have a list of validation errors in form of a Python dictionaries each.

Now if I try to raise it myself as a combined list against a key.

Something like,

```
  raise ValidationError({"items":[{'text': ['This field is required']}]})
```

I keep getting this message, `'ValidationError' object has no attribute 'error_list'`

Even If I simply try something like this in console, I get this message. Is there a way to get the ValidationError the way I want ?

**UPDATE** I did checkout the fix in 1.7.2 as mentioned by **@zymd**

This still doesn't get me what I want.

```
>>> raise ValidationError([{'key':'v'},{'key2':'v2'}])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['v', 'v2']
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug appears in django 1.7.1 (https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7.1/django/core/exceptions.py#L115) and older.

Upgrade your django to 1.7.2 (https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7.2/django/core/exceptions.py#L115).

Comment: True, there is a fix for that error but that just puts all the error messages in the same list bringing them out of the dictionary. Check my update to the question